# How to fix visibility="gone" causing stretchColumns in TableLayout to miscalculate widths?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout embedded within a HorizontalScrollView.  Some columns are hidden (`android:visibility="gone"`).  However, even though I have `android:stretchColumns="*"` on the TableLayout, the columns don't stretch to the full width.  Here is what I get:

```
<-----------------Screen Width---------------->
<---------HorizontalScrollView Width---------->
<---------TableLayout Width------------------->
<---------TableRow Width---------------------->
<-Col1-Col2-Col3-Col4-Col5->
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  If I physically delete from the XML layout the `gone` columns (Col6->Col9), then this renders as expected.  However, somehow setting the columns to gone has interfered with the stretchColumns.

```
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableLayout
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableRow 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:text="Col1"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:text="Col2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:text="Col3"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:text="Col4"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:text="Col5"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:text="Col6"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:text="Col7"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:text="Col8"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:text="Col9"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the TextViews `android:layout_weight="1"`. Better yet, because every one of your TextViews have the same style, just create a style for them in values/styles.xml file like this:

```
<style name="your_text_view_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
</style>
```

and instead of setting width and height for each view just give them this style in the layout xml.

```
style="@style/your_text_view_style"
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Thought I had tried every variation using layout weight, but clearly missed this one.